# Is it possible to use webkit or blink in an XUL application as the HTML rendering engine

Tags: javascript, webkit, xulrunner, blink

I am curious to know the possibility of using webkit component (or perhaps plugin) in an Mozilla's XUL based application (XULRunner). The idea is to use XUL as the primary user interface while webkit handles HTML page rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy and elegant way to accomplish that.

If you are interested in Webkit rendering engine, and **if** your code is not heavily dependent on XUL-specific features, you probably are looking for `nw.js`: http://nwjs.io .